# Differentiability of two variables featuring two equations

Tags: calculus

Hey i'm really confused with this question. It has two equations in one wing which doesn't make sense to me. The question goes...

> Is this function differentiable at the origin? 
>    $$f(x,y) = \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}, \, \frac{x^3-y^3}{x^2+y^2} \quad \text{if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$}  $$
>   $$   = (0,0) \qquad \text{if $(x,y) = (0,0)$} $$

Now i know that f is differentiable at x=a when...

$$ lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(a+h)-f(a) - (\alpha_1,\alpha_2,......\alpha_n)\begin{bmatrix} h_1\\h_2 \\.... \\ h_n\end{bmatrix}}{||h||}  $$

or for x,y 
$$ lim_{h_1, h_2 \to (0,0)} \frac{f(a+h_1, b+h_2)-f(a,b) - (\alpha_1,\alpha_2)\begin{bmatrix} h_1\\h_2 \end{bmatrix}}{\sqrt{h_1^2+h_2^2}}  $$

Where ||h|| at also equal
$$||h|| = \sqrt{(x-a)+(x-b)}$$

Alternatively if the partial derivatives exist and are continuous f is also differentiable.

I managed to get the partial deriviatives
$$\begin{bmatrix} \frac{df_1}{dx},\frac{df_2}{dx} \\ \frac{df_1}{dy},\frac{df_2}{dy}\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{y^2-x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2},-\frac{y(2x^3+3yx^2+y^3)}{{(x^2+y^2)^2}}\\ -\frac{2x}{(x^2+y^2)^2} ,\frac{x(x^3+y^2x+2y^3)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Ehm. *What's your question?* How to show that $f$ is differentiable? Where it is differentiable? Do you want to have your partial derivatives checked? Also, minor thing: you probably want to use $\partial$ instead of $d$ for your partial derivatives. :)

Comment: Hey i wanted to know how to check differentiability at the origin, i've updated the question.

Comment: Since you already calculated the partial derivatives, you can see that they are not continuous, so that's not helpful. (Nice idea though since this helps in many cases!) But it's easy to check that $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$ with $f(x_1,\ldots,x_m)=(f_1(x_1,\ldots,x_m),\ldots,f_m(x_1,\ldots,x_m))^T$ is differentiable if and only if the $f_1, \ldots, f_m$ are differentiable. So you can reduce the problem from your one function with "two equations" (i.e. $f: \text{something}\to\mathbb{R}^2$) to checking the two functions individually. Does that help to solve your confusion?

Comment: 1) How did  you say that it's not continuous? Is it because it is inconsistent at (0,0) i.e. the denominator become 0? Or did you have to do a limit 2) So you're saying i can condense this into one equaiton?

Comment: Also apparently i could also do this using "polar co-ordinates" is that i should do?

Comment: **1)** Well, yes-ish for "inconsistent". But you need to be careful. Consider for example $F(x)=x\sin (1/x)$ which can be continuously extended into $0$ by $F(0)=0$ even though $1/x$ is not defined for $x=0$. To make it rigorous in your situation use definition by sequences and look at the sequence $(x_n,0)$ for $x_n\to 0$ for example so $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}(x_n,0)\to (-\infty, 0)$. **2)** I'm saying you can check $f_1$ & $f_2$ individually for differentiability to decide on the differentiability of $f$. This should solve the "2 equ. in 1 doesn't make sense to me" problem.

Comment: **Yes**, moving to polar coordinates seems to be a great idea! *Not-so-important remark*: You repeatedly mixed things up while calculating the partial derivatives in the question. **i)** In the numerator of your computed $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y}$ should be $2xy$ instead of $2x$. **ii)** Your computed $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}$ misses a $3$ before the $y^2x$. **iii)** Your computed versions of $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y}$ should switch places.

Comment: But Piwi how would you go about using Polar co-ordinates?

Comment: Well, first of all start by evaluating the term inside your limit as far as that's possible. Then let $h_1=r \cos\varphi, h_2=r\sin\varphi$ and look at your limit again with $r\to 0$. You might want to have a look at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Converting_between_polar_and_Cartesian_coordinates) to understand what's going on.